# Interval of Solution and Absolute Value

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, absolute-value, integrating-factor

I am asked to find the general solution of the following ODE, as well as to give the largest interval of definition and determine if there are any transient terms in the general solution.

$$x\frac{dy}{dx} + (3x+1)y = e^{-3x}$$
[integratingfactorde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uQK1.jpg)

As far as I know, pic-related is the complete solution.  The book's solution insists I: (0,∞).

My question is why can't the interval be (-∞,0), because of the ln|x|?  Why do so many methods seem keen on dropping the abs(...) from the solution and give "just because" as an explanation?  Is there a mathematical reason for any of this or is dropping the abs(...) and setting the interval(s) to positive numbers just to make life easier?

Comment: Are you sure that this is all to the problem, no initial value indicated?

Comment: Yes.  It is part of section's problems focusing on solving ODEs with no initial value, yet still giving a specific interval.  That is what is making it so frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you can solve this ODE both on $(-∞,0)$ and on $(0,∞)$. Which one to choose depends on the initial value, if that is given for a negative $x$, then $ (-∞,0)$ is the domain of the solution. If one interval has to be selected, the convention for the default choice is the positive interval.

You can write down the solution more compactly if you use the integrating factor to compress the left side in the other direction, as done in the copied picture
$$
\frac{d}{dx}(xe^{3x}y(x))=xe^{3x}y'(x)+(3x+1)e^{3x}y(x)=1
$$
so that
$$
xe^{3x}y(x) = x+C.
$$
One should avoid the division by $x$ if in the next step a multiplication by $x$ cancels it out.

Comment: Thanks LutzL.  So it is convention to use the positive interval (presumably because it easier), therefore we drop the abs(...) from the antiderivative ln(...)?  I think I'm starting to see the light.  You just would think the book would specify what you just told me instead of making the students feel their answers were outright wrong.

Comment: Once you identify the form of the multiplier and get to the form in the book resp. the answer, there is no longer an absolute value. The derivation is valid for positive as for negative $x$, as the sign only amounts to a multiplicative constant in the homogeneous solution.

Comment: And yes, as the situation is qualitatively symmetric, it is allowed to prefer the positive interval if forced to select one of them.